# Can't connect Galaxy S2 to PC (Unknown Device)

Tags: usb, android

Trying to connect my SGS2 Android 4.1.2 to PC with Win7 Ultimate & Last Kies (USB driver version 1.5.29.0). Before yesterday phone connected successfully. Now hardware manager says Unknown Device.

Tried PC viral tests, re-installing drivers, but it takes no effect. Still not trying phone factory reset, but they say it is also useless. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the device and when offered to delete the device driver done so?  Because the way Windows keeps device drivers the best to resolve driver problems is to "delete" the device and the stored driver ( which would be used even if you uninstalled the device ).

Comment: @Ramhound sure, I had remove old drivers with which phone connected fine last time & then install last Kies, but it takes no effect

Comment: have you tried another computer and/or usb port.  Device drivers are stored per USB port.

Comment: @Ramhound I have no another PC, but I have tried other usb ports, but it takes no effect

Comment: There is too much that could be wrong to all mention in a comment (and an answer would just be a lot of links to internet with similar problems). You could try a different USB-cable (from Samsung). Please check [this topic](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1548253) for a lot of other suggestions.

Comment: have you tried restoring your PC to an early stage.. A date/time before this indecent occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by using new USB cable)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem but looking at all the topics about this on the internet does not guarantee this solution works for everyone.

What i did is going to Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Devices and printers. Under devices my phone was listed there but entering it's properties showed the it was not working properly (yellow exclamation mark). So i uninstalled the device, hardware tab > properties > driver tab uninstall. Then i reconnected my device, it installed automatically and it showed up under my computer again and i can enter the internal storage and SD card from there.